# How to make a subpath with no lines?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have this code to round sections in tableView:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)]) {
        CGFloat cornerRadius = 25.f;
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
        CAShapeLayer *layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 10, 0);
        if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
            CGPathAddRoundedRect(pathRef, nil, bounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
        } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
        } else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
        } else {
            // 
            // HERE IS THE PROBLEM:
            //
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
        }
        layer.path = pathRef;
        CFRelease(pathRef);
        //set the border color
        layer.strokeColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
        //set the border width
        layer.lineWidth = 1;
        layer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;

        UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
        [testView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
        cell.backgroundView = testView;
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Search Cell is the problem]

In **viewDidLoad** I used:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
```

The problem is the red cell "**Search**" getting red color. It seems that when I create each borderLine in **willDisplayCell** that cell in the middle I just draw left and right lines using moving pointer. If I draw a rectangle it works, but I don't want a rectangle..

How can I draw all the cell path without draw extra lines?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use a Grouped table?

Comment: What do you mean @matt ?

Comment: You can use an existing solution like https://github.com/TimOliver/TORoundedTableView but new in iOS 13 the `insetGrouped` table view just takes care of this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fill color for the layer won't work if you don't close the path (i.e. you need a closed path area to fill in).  It appears you're using `CGPathMoveToPoint` in certain spots where you really intending to be using `CGPathAddLineToPoint`

Here's what I believe you mean to do (which would close the path and allow the layer to fill it ):

```
            CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
            // start at top left
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, topLeft.x, topLeft.y);
            CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
            // line to top right
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, topRight.x, topRight.y);
            CGPoint botRight = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
            // line to bottom right
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, botRight.x, botRight.y);
            CGPoint botLeft = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
            // line to bottom left
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, botLeft.x, botLeft.y);
            // line back to top left now the path will be closed
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, topLeft.x, topLeft.y);
```

Really, I feel like you may be doing a lot of extra unnecessary work though.  If you're targeting iOS 11+, you should be able to use the `cell.layer.maskedCorners` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/2877488-maskedcorners?language=objc property to mask the proper corners based on which cell number in the section it is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0f;
    // only one row in section
    CACornerMask topCornerMask = kCALayerMinXMinYCorner | kCALayerMaxXMinYCorner;
    CACornerMask bottomCornerMask = kCALayerMinXMaxYCorner | kCALayerMaxXMaxYCorner;
    if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1) {
        // only one cell in section
        cell.layer.maskedCorners = topCornerMask | bottomCornerMask;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        // first cell in section
        cell.layer.maskedCorners = topCornerMask;
    } else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1) {
        // last cell in section
        cell.layer.maskedCorners = bottomCornerMask;
    } else {
        // middle cell, don't mask any corners
        cell.layer.maskedCorners = 0;
    }
}
```

Then you can just inset your whole tableview by leading 10 and trailing 10 and set your view background to the same color as your tableview (instead of insetting the path layer you were drawing)

**Edit:**

For the center cells, if you'd like to have one path/layer fill with white (with no lines and closed path) and one path/layer to draw the outside lines (left and right borders of the tableview) you're going to need to use two separate path/layers.  Here's a complete example of your willDisplayCell method creating two separate paths/layers:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)]) {
        CGColorRef strokeColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
        CGFloat cornerRadius = 25.f;
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
        CAShapeLayer *layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 10, 0);
        if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
            CGPathAddRoundedRect(pathRef, nil, bounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
        } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
        } else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
        } else {
            CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
            // start at top left
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, topLeft.x, topLeft.y);
            CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
            // line to top right
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, topRight.x, topRight.y);
            CGPoint botRight = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
            // line to bottom right
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, botRight.x, botRight.y);
            CGPoint botLeft = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
            // line to bottom left
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, botLeft.x, botLeft.y);
            // line back to top left now the path will be closed
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, topLeft.x, topLeft.y);
            // set the stroke path of our entire box to be clear (so it doesn't show lines)
            strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

            // now setup a path for the left and right border of the tableview (this is a center cell)
            CGMutablePathRef tableViewBorderPathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
            CAShapeLayer *tableViewBorderLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
            CGPathMoveToPoint(tableViewBorderPathRef, nil, topLeft.x, topLeft.y);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(tableViewBorderPathRef, nil, botLeft.x, botLeft.y);
            CGPathMoveToPoint(tableViewBorderPathRef, nil, topRight.x, topRight.y);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(tableViewBorderPathRef, nil, botRight.x, botRight.y);
            tableViewBorderLayer.path = tableViewBorderPathRef;
            tableViewBorderLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
            tableViewBorderLayer.lineWidth = 1.0f;
            [layer addSublayer:tableViewBorderLayer];
        }
        layer.path = pathRef;
        CFRelease(pathRef);
        //set the border color
        layer.strokeColor = strokeColor;
        //set the border width
        layer.lineWidth = 1.0f;
        layer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;

        UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
        [testView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
        cell.backgroundView = testView;
    }
```

Comment: Yes it works, but Im having the **same problem**. I mean, when I use your code it generate lines because it draws a rectangle of the cell. I just need to delimit this area without the lines of the rectangle. How can I make this? Thank you @R4N !

Comment: @JaredPérez I've edited my response above to show modified code to draw two separate paths -- one for the white fillColor (closed path) and one of the tableview left and right borders